# Dispatcher.Invoke analogue for .net 2.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-binding

I'm using DataBindings in my .net application, and there are places, where i update some UI values from secondary threads. So, I need to invoke to main UI thread to perform GUI operations without exceptions.

in .net 3 world I could say `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ /* update UI here */} );` but now I'm working with .net 2.0 only.

At these places I have no access to any gui Control to do Control.Invoke either.
So, how can I safely update my UI in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe `Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke` ?

Comment: thanks, that works. I'm just not sure, what's that :) Is that the first form that was created by app? What if it was already disposed?..

Comment: Those are the currently open forms. It doesn't have to be the main form. So if you are creating new windows on other threads than the main UI thread, you might run into problems with that.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 2.0 and Windows Forms you will have to use the `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` methods of the control to update the UI from a background thread.

MSDN has the [following sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx):

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

private void Invoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myTextBox.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethod));
}
public void InvokeMethod()
{
   myTextBox.Text = "Executed the given delegate";
}
```

Comment: `I have no access to any gui Control to do Control.Invoke either`. Yes, I know that way, but no Controls are easily accessible.

Comment: @Shaddix: If you don't have a GUI control, what UI are you going to update then?

Comment: I do have UI, I have no access to it at the point, where I'm updating it. I use DataBindings and TextBox.Text property is bound to someClass.Text property, so when I'm changing someClass.Text I automatically got the UI updated. And inside someClass I have no access to UI at all

Answer (score 3):

It's all the same answers. Take an instance reference for a ui control (as those always run on the main thread), check if it's still there, and let it invoke the code you want to be run on the main thread. Stupid .NET 2.0, but works. If your code is in a form, you can even just use:

```
BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate{your.code.here();even.more.code.here();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select a design pattern that will help you do the same.

A class, which has access to the form (or its object), should be used for delegating the action to the form. This class maybe used by threads (make sure it's all synchronized).

Edit:

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AOPInvokeRequired.aspx) might interest you too!

Comment: I'm currently using static reference to my main form, so it seems like what you've advised. It works, but with Dispatcher it much cleaner.. thought, there's something similar in .net 2.0. Unfortunately it seems, that there's no :(

Answer (score 0):

when i have that need i always create a method that starts with

```
If (control.InvokeRequired)
{
    control.Invoke([This method], params);
    return;
}
```

and then execute what is needed to run on the ui, this way you can just call this method and it will run on the UI thread..